# nHibernate: limit the result set of a mapped collection

Tags: nhibernate

How do you limit the result set of a mapped collection in nHibernate? For instance:

```
Model.Items;
```

will always return all the Items for the given Model. Is there any way to force it to return only, say, 20 Items **without creating a specific query** ? Something like

```
Model.Items.SetMaxResults(20);
```

In other words, I would like nHibernate to return IQueryable instead of a simple IList, when I access a collection.

**Update.** Although I have accepted the answer, I would like to point out that this is not in line with nHibernate's intended way of usage, and a child collection should be loaded and limited within a separate query.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve and how big are the Items collections typically?

Comment: Few hundred items being lazy loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be accomplished with a filter:

```
IQuery q = nhSession.CreateFilter(Parent.ChildCollection, "select count(*)");
long countResult = q.UniqueResult<long>();
```

as you see the filter in an IQuery and you are not limited to the "select count" paradigm i just gave.
Additionally, this solution requires a normal collection mapped so you can use it in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

.SetProjection(Projections.Property("Items"))
.SetMaxResults(20)

Comment: using System.Linq; 

IList results = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Model))
    .SetProjection(...).list();

IQueryable q = results.AsQueryable();

Comment: Nhibernate has this parameter for mapping collections <batch-size="N">. But it seems, this is something different that you want, I think. So only Criteria allows to control fetching records dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `<loader />` mapping element to specify a query that will load the collection. More information can be found [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-load).

Comment: This is cool, but it won't let me specify parameters for LIMIT at the point of access to the collection, which is what I would like to have.